# Flutter Plugin -- build for iOS works in xCode, but doesn't work with flutter build because of package dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a Flutter plugin, which requires a third party library. This library is hosted on GitHub, and to add it to my project, they tell me to use XCode's package manager (File -> Add Packages). When I do it this way, I can use the package just fine, compile my code and run it on my iPad. However, when I try to use "flutter build ios", it doesn't work.

When building, I see a series of (with actual framework names and file names instead of ...):

```
    note: Removed stale file ...
    note: Removed stale file ...
    note: Removed stale file ...
```

Then eventually I will see that the compilation has failed due to being unable to import the library I need. Additionally, when I go back into XCode, I find that the package dependency I had installed is no longer there.

So, what I suspect is happening, is when Flutter builds it is cleaning up all the old frameworks, and running its own `pod install`. However, since my package is not part of my podspec file, it is being left behind. I am unsure how to get this to work. I've tried adding a line in my podspec file like:

```
s.dependency 'PackageName'
s.source { :git => 'https://linkToTheGitRepo' }
```

and then running `pod repo update`, but when I go to build I still get "Unable to find a specification for `PackageName` depended upon by `my_plugin`".

At this point, I just build in XCode and then don't touch it, however this has also caused issues when I go to use the plugin later in another project -- I also cannot use `flutter build ios` in that project, and I have to do it through XCode. This is an annoying workaround, since I lose the hot reload ability and other nice features of working with Flutter. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.